# How to write an Http Trigger Azure Function with output binding?

Tags: azure-functions

All the Http Trigger samples in the documentation are implemented as async function which doesn't support [out] parameter. Does that mean output binding is not available to any Http/Webhook triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vincent,

Although the documentation and templates show functions using async methods, that's mostly because of some of the scenarios they cover. Functions are not required to be `async`, you're also not required to return a `Task` from your HTTP or WebHook trigger functions and can change them to `void` (or an appropriate type), so you can change the method signature to meet your requirements.

Also, bindings only require `out` parameters for *some* parameter types. Most bindings support multiple types. A detailed description of the most common bindings and their supported types is available here:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!Am_1X5sjRkhpgQUscoXoIk6dpI34

I hope this helps!

Comment: Fabio, after I removed the async await pair from the the code, everything works. Thanks for pointing out the webjob documentation, a reminder that Azure function is built on top of WebJob.

Comment: Fabio, link is dead - do you mind updating it please?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. For some reason, the document has been removed, so I've updated the link pointing to a copy I have shared. Let me know if you have any issues with it.